# Return a single row but with additional columns in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a function which returns a single row of a table, but some additional columns from other tables it can be joint with. How can I do that? Should I declare a new type? Or should I return the table type?

Comment: You can explain your problem a litle better, show us what have you tried. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, what's not clear?

Comment: Not really, and you didnt show any effort neither, Even when you know something about new type and table type. So looks kind a lazy question.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, what effort? There's nothing to show here.

Comment: I mean you didnt show what have you tried. This isnt `do it for me` site. You try something, get stuck, ask for help and we teach you what was wrong.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, so why have I received 2 answers already?

Comment: You can stubbornly persist that your question is alright, even though the two links that Juan Carlos Oropeza provided clearly show that your question is lacking is virtually all aspects, or you could take his well-intended advice and learn. Yes, you have two answers (one of which states "Based on the tiny amount of information you have provided") of which neither is very specific, but you also have three close-votes given by people who have been around for a while. Since your reputation stands at 1 it can't go any lower, surely you would have down-votes too if you had had any reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return value of the table's composite type, because then you would not be able to add the additional columns.

You could either:

1. Declare a new composite type containing the columns you want to return, or
2. Return a RECORD type, which doesn't have any fixed structure. In that scenario you would be returning the resulting row of a query which extracted the row of the table joined to the other tables.

Based on the tiny amount of information you have provided, a RECORD would be easiest.

See:

- [Supported Argument and Result Data Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-overview.html#PLPGSQL-ARGS-RESULTS)
- [Row Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ROWTYPES)
- [Record Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS)

**UPDATE**: After testing using a record type, they turn out to be somewhat inconvenient to use. Consider this example:

```
CREATE TABLE a(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, foo TEXT, bar INT);
CREATE TABLE b(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, aid INT, baz TEXT);
INSERT INTO a(foo,bar) VALUES('apples', 25);
INSERT INTO b(aid, baz) VALUES(1, 'bananas');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST(p_id INT) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT a.id,foo,bar,baz FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id=b.aid WHERE A.ID=p_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If you naively try to use it like this:

```
psql=> SELECT * FROM TEST(1);
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM TEST(1);
                      ^
```

In fact, every time you want to call it, you would have to specify a column definition list like this:

```
psql=> SELECT * FROM TEST(1) AS test(id int, foo text, bar int, baz text);
 id |  foo   | bar |   baz
----+--------+-----+---------
  1 | apples |  25 | bananas
(1 row)
```

So, if that's your intended use case, then I recommend following the approach outlined by [Craig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777435/1411457).

Answer (score 2):

Use `RETURNS TABLE` and enumerate all the columns of the original table as well as all the new columns.

See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html).

Or alternately, you can return the table-type plus the extra columns, so you produce a composite-typed field, e.g.

```
RETURNS TABLE (tablerow table_type, extracol1 integer, extracol2 text)
```